# Create an ActiveMQ Artemis server and send a message on queue through it inside a JUnit test

Tags: spring-boot, junit, activemq-artemis

I have a Spring Boot application that receives messages on an ActiveMQ Artemis queue and I am trying to write some junit tests to verify that my consumers correctly receive messages.

I am using Spring Boot 3.0.x, and since ActiveMQ Artemis recently added support for JUnit 5 I am trying to use the `artemis-junit-5 module` for my tests.

I followed their guide and declared:

```java
    @RegisterExtension
    private EmbeddedActiveMQExtension server = new EmbeddedActiveMQExtension();
```

And then I start the server and create the queue:

```java
    @BeforeEach
    void setup() {
        server.start();
        server.createQueue("tcp://localhost:61616", "QUEUE");
    }
```

This is my test:

```java
    @Test
    @DisplayName("Test receive message from queue")
    void receiveEventTest() {
        Event message = TestUtils.createMockEvent ("test", "test", 1L);
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(message);
        Mockito.verify(service).save(any());
        Mockito.verify(repository).save(any());
    }
```

However, when I launch the test I get this error:

```
org.springframework.jms.UncategorizedJmsException: Uncategorized exception occurred during JMS processing; nested exception is ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]

    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.convertJmsAccessException(JmsUtils.java:310)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.convertJmsAccessException(JmsAccessor.java:184)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:507)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:584)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:661)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.convertAndSend(JmsTemplate.java:650)
    at com.soldo.compliance.notification.service.CompanyUpdateEventReceiveMessageTest.receiveCompanyUpdaterealMessageTest(CompanyUpdateEventReceiveMessageTest.java:49)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: jakarta.jms.JMSException: Failed to create session factory
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:897)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:291)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:286)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:196)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:494)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ219007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:701)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.java:895)
    ... 78 more
```

I guess this is due to the fact that `EmbeddedActiveMQExtension` according to the documentation runs a server without the JMS Manager and so I should be using `EmbeddedJMSExtension` that instead includes the JMS Manager.
My problem is that `EmbeddedJMSExtension` is not present in `artemis-junit-5`, and I cannot find anywhere information on what I should use instead. Can anyone help me?

EDIT:
Following my JMS configuration

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableJms
public class JmsConfig {

    @Bean("jmsConnectionFactory")
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory(@Value("${spring.artemis.broker-url}") String brokerUrl) {
        return new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(brokerUrl);
    }

    @Bean("jmsContainerFactory")
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory(
            @Qualifier("jmsConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory
    ) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean("jmsMessageConverter")
    public MessageConverter messageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        messageConverter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        messageConverter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_TYPE_ID");
        messageConverter.setTypeIdMappings(Map.of("Event1", Event1.class,
                "Event2", Event2.class));
        messageConverter.setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper());
        return messageConverter;
    }

    @Bean("jmsTemplate")
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(
            @Value("${jms.queue}") String jmsQueue,
            @Qualifier("jmsConnectionFactory") ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            @Qualifier("jmsMessageConverter") MessageConverter messageConverter
    ) {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);
        jmsTemplate.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
        jmsTemplate.setDefaultDestinationName(jmsQueue);
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

}
```

And my `application.properties`:

```
spring.artemis.broker-url=vm://0
spring.artemis.mode=embedded
spring.artemis.embedded.enabled=true
jms.queue=QUEUE
```

EDIT2:
As of now, I am able to receive the messages I send in the test only if I receive them in the same test. The `JMSListener` in my Spring Boot app never receive anything. I read that the server created through `EmbeddedActiveMQExtension` does not support external connection by default. Might that be the problem and should I try to allow it to receive connections from outside?

I tried also with the following `application.properties`:

```
spring.artemis.broker-url=vm://0
spring.artemis.mode=native
spring.artemis.embedded.enabled=false
jms.queue=QUEUE
```

**UPDATE**

After a few more days struggling with it, I finally got it working. The issue should be in how the queue was declared and in its binding.
I got to this conclusion when I found the following logs in the test start up

```
10:12:07.714 [main] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.postoffice.impl.PostOfficeImpl - PostOffice::simpleRoute null as bindings
10:12:07.714 [main] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.postoffice.impl.PostOfficeImpl - Couldn't find any bindings for address=activemq.notifications on message=CoreMessage[messageID=4,durable=true,userID=null,priority=0, timestamp=Wed Feb 15 10:12:07 CET 2023,expiration=0, durable=true, address=activemq.notifications,size=752,properties=TypedProperties[_AMQ_Binding_Type=0,_AMQ_RoutingName=compliance.infocamere.monitoring.results,_AMQ_Distance=0,_AMQ_Address=compliance.infocamere.monitoring.results,_AMQ_NotifType=BINDING_ADDED,_AMQ_Binding_ID=2,_AMQ_NotifTimestamp=1676452327713,_AMQ_ClusterName=compliance.infocamere.monitoring.resultsd21cadc1-ad10-11ed-b98b-e2f75c73417f]]@465233746
10:12:07.724 [main] DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.postoffice.impl.PostOfficeImpl - Message CoreMessage[messageID=4,durable=true,userID=null,priority=0, timestamp=Wed Feb 15 10:12:07 CET 2023,expiration=0, durable=true, address=activemq.notifications,size=752,properties=TypedProperties[_AMQ_Binding_Type=0,_AMQ_RoutingName=compliance.infocamere.monitoring.results,_AMQ_Distance=0,_AMQ_Address=compliance.infocamere.monitoring.results,_AMQ_NotifType=BINDING_ADDED,_AMQ_Binding_ID=2,_AMQ_NotifTimestamp=1676452327713,_AMQ_ClusterName=compliance.infocamere.monitoring.resultsd21cadc1-ad10-11ed-b98b-e2f75c73417f]]@465233746 is not going anywhere as it didn't have a binding on address:activemq.notifications
10:12:07.746 [main] INFO org.apache.activemq.audit.base - AMQ601019: User anonymous@unknown is getting mbean info on target resource: org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.management.impl.QueueControlImpl@51ec2df1
```

I did a few more tests using the default configuration for the test

```
    @RegisterExtension
    private static EmbeddedActiveMQExtension server = new EmbeddedActiveMQExtension();
```

but I could not make it work.

In the end, I found some configuration example files for jms in the middle of Artemis tests (you can find them [here](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/main/artemis-junit/artemis-junit-5/src/test/resources)). I took the embedded-artemis-jms-server.xml and adapted it to my needs and changed the EmbeddedActiveMQExtension initialization to use the file and finally got everything working.

Following the configuration I used

**embedded-artemis-jms.xml**

```
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xsi:schemaLocation="
               urn:activemq /schema/artemis-server.xsd
               urn:activemq:core /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd
               urn:activemq:jms /schema/artemis-jms.xsd">

    <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core">
        <persistence-enabled>false</persistence-enabled>
        <security-enabled>false</security-enabled>

        <!-- Acceptors -->
        <acceptors>
            <acceptor name="in-vm">vm://0</acceptor>
        </acceptors>
    </core>

    <jms xmlns="urn:activemq:jms">
        <queue name="queue.name">
            <durable>true</durable>
        </queue>

    </jms>
</configuration>
```

**server initialization**

```
    @RegisterExtension
    private static EmbeddedActiveMQExtension server = new EmbeddedActiveMQExtension("embedded-artemis-jms.xml");
```

**application.properties**

```
jms.queue=queue.name
spring.artemis.embedded.enabled=false
spring.artemis.mode=native
spring.jms.pub-sub-domain=false
spring.jms.cache.consumers=true
```

**jms listener configuration**

```
 @JmsListener(destination = "${jms.queue}"")
```

**send a message on the queue**

```
    public static final String QUEUE_NAME = "queue.name";

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @Test
    void sendMessageTest() {
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(QUEUE_NAME, your_event);
    }
```

Comment: Is your Spring code not running as part of your unit test in the same JVM as the `EmbeddedActiveMQExtension`? If so, it should be able to connect to the embedded broker no problem.

Comment: It is part of the same JVM

Answer (score 1):

The problem *isn't* that you need `EmbeddedJMSExtension`. The `EmbeddedActiveMQExtension` should be sufficient for you.

The problem is that your Spring JMS component is not configured properly to connect to the in-vm acceptor of the embedded instance of ActiveMQ Artemis. You need to configure your Spring JMS component to connect to `vm://0` instead of the usual `tcp://host:port` URL.

Also, this call doesn't really make sense:

```java
server.createQueue("tcp://localhost:61616", "QUEUE");
```

The 2 `String` objects used by this overloaded `createQueue` method are for the name of the **address** and **queue** respectively. You almost certainly don't want the address to be named `tcp://localhost:61616`. In fact, you shouldn't *need* to create any queues at all because the broker will automatically create addresses & queues as needed during runtime by default.

Finally, I believe the documentation you cited is simply incorrect. There is, in fact, no object named `EmbeddedJMSExtension` to be used with JUnit 5. Furthermore, the `EmbeddedJMSResource` for use with JUnit 4 is *deprecated* and has this comment:

> Deprecated in favor of EmbeddedActiveMQResource. Since Artemis 2.0 all JMS specific broker management classes, interfaces, and methods have been deprecated in favor of their more general counter-parts.

Here's a simple example...

`pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <groupId>org.example</groupId>
   <artifactId>artemis-junit-test</artifactId>
   <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
         <artifactId>artemis-junit-5</artifactId>
         <version>2.28.0</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
         <version>5.9.2</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
         <version>5.9.2</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit-platform-runner</artifactId>
         <version>1.2.0</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</project>
```

`TestEmbeddedActiveMQExtension.java`:

```java
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSContext;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;

import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client.ActiveMQClient;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client.ClientConsumer;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client.ClientMessage;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client.ClientProducer;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client.ClientSession;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client.ClientSessionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.client.ServerLocator;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.junit.EmbeddedActiveMQExtension;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.RegisterExtension;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

public class TestEmbeddedActiveMQExtension {

   @RegisterExtension
   private EmbeddedActiveMQExtension server = new EmbeddedActiveMQExtension();

   @Test
   public void testJMS1_1() throws Exception {
      final String QUEUE = "myQueue";
      server.start();
      ConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://0");
      Connection c = cf.createConnection();
      c.start();
      Session s = c.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
      Destination d = s.createQueue(QUEUE);
      MessageProducer p = s.createProducer(d);
      p.send(s.createMessage());
      MessageConsumer consumer = s.createConsumer(d);
      Message m = consumer.receive(500);
      server.stop();
      assertNotNull(m);
   }

   @Test
   public void testJMS2() throws Exception {
      final String QUEUE = "myQueue";
      server.start();
      ConnectionFactory cf = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://0");
      JMSContext c = cf.createContext();
      Destination d = c.createQueue(QUEUE);
      c.createProducer().send(d, c.createMessage());
      Message m = c.createConsumer(d).receive(500);
      server.stop();
      assertNotNull(m);
   }

   @Test
   public void testCore() throws Exception {
      final String QUEUE = "myQueue";
      server.start();
      server.createQueue(QUEUE);
      ServerLocator locator = ActiveMQClient.createServerLocator("vm://0");
      ClientSessionFactory csf = locator.createSessionFactory();
      ClientSession s = csf.createSession();
      s.start();
      ClientProducer p = s.createProducer(QUEUE);
      p.send(s.createMessage(true));
      ClientConsumer c = s.createConsumer(QUEUE);
      ClientMessage m = c.receive(500);
      server.stop();
      assertNotNull(m);
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and configured vm://0 as address to connect to for the test but the listener still does not receive anything. Anything else I need to setup? About the createQueue, I was following a guide I found online and the tests Artemis has on its github they use it and that's why I put it there. I tried removing it just now but I get an error stating that the queue does not exists

Comment: I updated my answer with a simple example demonstrating how to connect to the broker started by the `EmbeddedActiveMQExtension`. In your use-case you may actually have some interference with Spring Boot itself as I believe it will start its own embedded broker with the configuration you're using. I'm not a Spring expert so I can't really comment further on that aspect.

Comment: Can you provide the URL for the guide and/or for the tests you used for `createQueue`? I don't see anything in the ActiveMQ Artemis documentation or tests that pass a URL to `createQueue`. You'd need to provide more details about the "queue does not exist" error you're seeing for me to comment further there.

Comment: I was looking here https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/main/artemis-junit/artemis-junit-5/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/junit/EmbeddedActiveMQResourceTest.java and https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/unit-testing.html
they put "test.address" so I guessed I should have put the URL address of Artemis bu tI just tried and it works no matter the string I put as first parameter.
The error comes out if I completely remove the call to createQueue

Comment: If I send and receive a message inside the same test, everything works fine. What I am struggling with is sending a message from the test and receiving it with the consumer inside the spring boot app. I will update the question with some more information

Comment: The "address" String passed to `createQueue` is _not_ a URL. It is the endpoint where messages are sent as defined by the broker's [address model](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-model.html#address).